# ionic angularjs http POST 404 not found

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using ionic 2.2.1 and angularjs 1.6.1. My backend is using node.js 6.9.2 with koajs

I created my project using ionic 1
ionic start myproject sidemenu

I keep getting POST 404 not found when calling my API URL

I already did the following

install cordova whitelist
**https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist**

**backend node.js**

```
import Koa from 'koa';
const app = new Koa();
const koaBody = require('koa-body')();
const cors = require('kcors');
app.use(cors());

router.post('/loginUser', koaBody, async function (ctx, next) {

   console.log("loginUser");

   ctx.body = 'Cool POST';

});

router.get('/', koaBody, async function (ctx, next) {

   ctx.body = 'Hello GET';

});
```

**index.html (add or remove below line in index.html also the same and doesn't help at all)**

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' * data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; frame-src 'self' https://cordova.apache.org">
```

if directly paste the API URL (http://www.yourkeyhere.com:7272/) in browser, I got correct response. Hence this is not the server side issue.

**POST always 404**

```
      $http({
           method: 'POST',
           url: 'http://www.yourkeyhere.com:7272/loginUser'
      }).then(function successCallback(response) {

      }, function errorCallback(response) {

      });
```

**GET ok**

```
      $http({
           method: 'GET',
           url: 'http://www.yourkeyhere.com:7272/'
      }).then(function successCallback(response) {

      }, function errorCallback(response) {

      });
```

I tested in both Chrome browser (**ionic serve**) and iPhone (**ionic run ios --device --consolelogs --serverlogs**)

This problem doesn't exist when pointing to localhost server

I have been searching google and SO here but all the solution doesn't work at all.

Comment: Looks like `http://www.myproject.com:7272/loginUser` is not valid endpoint so the server repsonse with 404. Check your backend and make your routes/actions listen to that ENDPOINT. CORS doesnt matter here because the HTTP-Status code is created by your backend/Server application.

Comment: @Mark what's your allow access origin setting in config.xml  ??

Comment: Please add your koa application code. Especiallythe route configuration which is  listening on `/loginUser`.

Comment: @Gandhi when testing in browser, config.xml doesn't apply right?

Comment: this problem is really funny. a simple POST request causing a lot of people scratching head and wasted lot of time

Comment: This problem doesn't exist when pointing to localhost server

Comment: @MarkThien If you test it via browser platform it matters i guess

Comment: Was a solution/workaround to this found? I'm facing the same problem. From server log, I notice that the POST request has the correct 'Host' header, and with full request path (unlike GET that has only the relative path).

Comment: Sorry it is my mistake. I install koajs body version 1. It should be version 2. After installing version 2 problem solved. Cool man !!